# Django url wrong

Tags: python, django, url, frameworks, get

I'm new in django and I'm reading a tutorial and it have an example but I think is a old Django version and now I'm using Django 1.4

```
views.py


 from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)

def hours_ahead(request, offset):
    offset = int(offset)
    dt = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    html = "<html><body>In %s hour(s), it will be %s.</body></html>" % (offset, dt)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

and the urls.py file

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import current_datetime, hours_ahead

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^time/$', current_datetime),
    (r'^time/plus/\d{1,2}/$', hours_ahead),


)
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your URL pattern is missing parenthesis to show that you want to capture the offset from the URL. Try changing it to the following:

```
(r'^time/plus/(\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
```

Often, people prefer to use [named groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#named-groups) in their URL patterns. In your case, the URL pattern would change to:

```
(r'^time/plus/(?P<offset>\d{1,2})/$', hours_ahead),
```

Answer (score 0):

So rather than importing the views module for that app and the given handler's you're supposed to supply a string I believe, so this should work for your urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from mysite.views import current_datetime, hours_ahead

urlpatterns = patterns('',
     (r'^time/$', 'mysite.views.current_datetime'),
     (r'^time/plus/\d{1,2}/$', 'mysite.views.hours_ahead'),

)
```